# How to assign value to TextArea using Javascript, using class name rather than Id to link the two?

Tags: javascript

I am missing something simple here. I need to preprocess a textarea before it being posted back to the server. I can link the button to the textarea using Id, but not sure how to do it via class name which would be more reusable.

Code with Id:

```
<textarea id="Comment" class="CleanHTML"></teaxtarea>

<button type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" value="Save" onClick='document.getElementById("Comment").value = cleanWordClipboard(document.getElementById("Comment").value)'>Save</button>
```

How would I alter my onClick JS to use the Class "CleanHTML", rather than Id to reference the TextArea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `document.getElementById('Comment')`, use `document.getElementsByClassName('CleanHTML')[0]`

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns an HTMLCollection (which can be treated like an array for our purposes), which is why you need the `[0]`. If you have multiple elements with that class name, then you obviously need to adjust the index accordingly.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.CleanHTML')` could also work from IE9+. `getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList not an array.

Comment: Thanks for this prompt reply. Yes I was wondering how one deals with multiple elements as in my situation one still needs to update the specific element with the correct processed value, not all elements with the same processed value.

Comment: Thanks @EdCottrell, Really appreciate the prompt answer.